# How to turn off sounds in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, system-sounds

I do not want TortoiseSVN to alert me with sounds - e.g. when it fails to update.

How do I turn off sounds in TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click > TortoiseSVN > Settings > System Sounds..

Scroll down to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the Sounds panel in Control Panel.